# Finding "decent" numbers algorithm reasoning?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

## Problem

Sherlock Holmes is getting paranoid about Professor Moriarty, his archenemy. All his efforts to subdue Moriarty have been in vain. These days Sherlock is working on a problem with Dr. Watson. Watson mentioned that the CIA has been facing weird problems with their supercomputer, 'The Beast', recently.

This afternoon, Sherlock received a note from Moriarty, saying that he has infected 'The Beast' with a virus. Moreover, the note had the number N printed on it. After doing some calculations, Sherlock figured out that the key to remove the virus is the largest 'Decent' Number having N digits.

A 'Decent' Number has -

- 3 or 5 or both as its digits.
- No other digit is allowed.
- Number of times 3 appears is divisible by 5.
- Number of times 5 appears is divisible by 3.

Meanwhile, the counter to destruction of 'The Beast' is running very fast. Can you save 'The Beast', and find the key before Sherlock?

Input Format
The 1st line will contain an integer T, the number of test cases. This is followed by T lines, each containing an integer N i.e. the number of digits in the number

Output Format
Largest Decent number having N digits. If no such number exists, tell Sherlock that he is wrong and print '-1'

Constraints
1<=T<=20
1<=N<=100000

#### Sample Input

```
4
1
3
5
11
```

#### Sample Output

```
-1
555
33333
55555533333
```

Explanation
For N=1, there is no such number.

For N=3, 555 is only possible number.

For N=5, 33333 is only possible number.

For N=11, 55555533333 and all of permutations of digits are valid numbers, among them, the given number is the largest one.

## Answer

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n = int(input())
    c = 5*(2*n%3)
    if c > n:
        print(-1)
    else:
        print('5' * (n-c) + '3'*c)
```

## Question

Can someone explain the reasoning behind it? Specifically what the assignment for the 'c' variable is doing?

Source: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-the-beast

Comment: Well, first, `2*n%3` is going to be `0` if `n` is divisible by 3, `2` if it's `n-1` is divisible by 3, `1` if `n+1` is divisible by 3. So, `c` is going to be `0`, `10`, or `5` in those three cases. (Print out `[5*(2*n%3) for n in range(20)]` if it's still not clear.) And notice what `c` is being useful for—you have `n-c` 5's, and `c` 3's. Is that enough to figure it out?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A mathematical solution:

Let a = len of the '5's, b = len of the '3's. So

`a + b = N`

We know that 3 divides a, and 5 divides b, so let a = 3n, b = 5m

`3n+5m = N`

This is a diophantine equation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) with one solution being (n0, m0) = (2N, -N), and general solution

`(n,m) = (5k+2N, 3K-N), k any integer`

The problem now is to minimize the quantity 3k-N (**because you want MORE '5's**), so that 3k-N > 0.
This is the same as finding the k for which 3k is the next multiple of 3 FROM N.

For example, if N = 10 or 11, we are looking for 3k = 12, or k = 4.

3k-N is therefore the distance between N and this next multiple of 3. The author of the solution claims that 3k-N = 2N%3 , and you prove this by exhaustion, evaluating the case for which N%3 = 0, 1, and 2. For the record, the '2' in the expression '2N%3' isn't unique, it would work for any number of the sequence 2, 5, 8, 11..., and why the author chose this particular expression, I cannot say.

You can also think about how N%3 in this sense is how close N is to the next LOWER multiple of 3.

Comment: Shouldn't the solution be `(n,m) = (2N + 5k, -N -3K), k any integer`?
Because for what is written in wikipeida page : `if (x, y) is a solution, then the other solutions have the form (x + kv, y - ku), where k is an arbitrary integer, and u and v are the quotients of a and b (respectively) by the greatest common divisor of a and b.` So `x=2N, y=-N, v=5, u=3` you are assuming `u=-3`, Why? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

OK, the thinking goes something like this.

1. Once you've worked out how many `5`s and how many `3`s you want, you should front-load the `5`s. The ordering makes no odds to whether the number is decent; but it'll be bigger if the `5`s are at the front.
2. The number of `3`s you want should be the smallest number that satisfies the constraints, because then you'll have more `5`s, making for a bigger number.
3. The number of `3`s must be divisible by 5. That means that there's never any point having more than 10 `3`s: you should only consider 0, 5 or 10 `3`s. This is because you want the smallest number that leaves the number of remaining digits divisible by 3, to satisfy the other constraint. If having 15 `3`s works, then so does having 0 `3`s; if 20 works, then so does 5; if 25 works, then so does 10. In general, subtracting 15 from the number of `3`s will leave the constraints both still satisfied if they were before.
4. The number of `5`s must therefore be `n-0` or `n-5` or `n-10`, and we want the one that gives a number that's divisible by 3. The calculation `c = 5*(2*n%3)` will give you 0 `3`s and therefore `n` `5`s if `n` was already divisible by 3; and 10 `3`s and therefore `n-10` `5`s if `n` was one greater than a multiple of 3, in which case `n-10` is still divisible by 3; and so on.
5. The only thing to test is whether the calculation of `c` `3`s and `n-c` `5`s satisfies the implicit constraint that `n-c` should be non-negative. If it's negative then there's no solution; if it's non-negative then this is a valid solution and front-loading the `5`s will give you the largest such solution.

This is one of quite a wide class of "programming" problems where the test isn't really to see whether you can bash out some code that does the job, but to see whether you can reduce the problem logically to the point where it's trivial and can be solved very efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I think the math helped a bit and I read up on the different parts of it and the history. My solution passed all 15 tests first time so while I did not use the math my take on this may help you. I handled 10 and less as edge cases which I just hard coded. Anything above 10 I divided by 3 to get the most “555”s out. Of course when dividing by 3 the remainder can only be 0, 1 or 2. Zero of course means just write 555 however many times. One means subtract 3 of the 555s to get back to 10 open slots for the 10 threes. Two means subtract 1 of the 555s which leaves 5 slots for a 33333.

3 ifs for the remainders.
10 ifs for the edge cases.
1 if for the constraints.
1 for.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(raw_input())
while x!= 0 :
    y=int(raw_input())
    z=y
    while(z%3!=0):
        z-=5
    if(z<0):
        print '-1'
    else:
        print z*'5'+(y-z)*'3'
    x = x-1
```

If the number(say 66317) is not divisible by 3, it will leave a modulo of either 0,1 or 2. If I decrease the number by 5, I am basically making it a multiple of 3, and the remaning digits will be a multiple of 5 as I am subtracting it from the number.

modulo 0 implies number divisibile modulo 1 implies 5 needs to be subtracted twice. modulo 2 implies 5 needs to be subtracted once.